# (Python) List Index out of range error

Tags: python

This function returns a ListIndex error on line 8. I try to calculate the sum of all squared values in the nList:

```
def oneVolume(n):
  j = 0
  Sum = 0
  nList = []
  for i in range (n):
    nList.append(2*random()-1)
    while j <= n:
      Sum = Sum +nList[j] # line with list index error
      j = j+1
  return Sum
```

Comment: are you just trying to `sum` `nList`?  Try `sum(nList)`.

Comment: i want to square each value in the list and then sum all the squared values

Comment: @user3349164 `sum([x**2 for x in nList])`

Comment: @user3349164 or in similar flavor as @loki, `sum(map(lambda x: x**2, nList))
`

Answer (score 2):

```
while j <= n:
```

Should be

```
while j < n;
```

`range(5) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. There is no `5` element (but there are five elements, because there's a `0`)

---

But this isn't the pythonic approach. Iterate *over the list* instead of *a range the size of the list*:

```
def oneVolume(n):
    Sum = 0
    nList = []
    for i in range(n):
        nList.append(2*random()-1)
    for j in nList:
        Sum = Sum + j
    return Sum
```

---

But you can go a whole lot further in simplifying, using a generator and the built-in sum function:

```
def oneVolume(n):
    return sum(2*random()-1 for _ in range(n))
```

The generator is a lot like a list, `[2*random()-1 for _ in range(n)]`, only more transient. That gets passed to the `sum`, which automatically does what you intended by the second half of your function.

Answer (score 0):

You have an off by 1 error.

```
l = []
l.append(1)
l.append(2)
l.append(3)
```

l will that 3 elements. They will be l[0] (containing 0), l[1], and l[2]

len(l) will be 3

referencing l[3] will be an index out of bounds.